# How to fix my code when using springcloud gateway to jump to url according to body condition?

Tags: spring, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to determine based on the value of the body in the post, jump to a different address according to different conditions, and pass the body and client IP when jumping. What is the mistake in the following writing? It return the error msg:

> {
> "timestamp": 1687917352552,
> "status": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "message": "Not Found",
> "path": "/myroute"
> }

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

@Bean 
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
            return builder.routes()
                    .route("route1", r -> r.path("/myroute")
                            .and().header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                            .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> {
                                if (requestBody.contains("baidu")) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }) 
                            .uri("http://www.baidu.com"))

                    .route("route2", r -> r.path("/myroute")
                            .and().header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                            .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> {
                                if (requestBody.contains("so")) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }) 
                            .uri("https://www.so.com/"))
                    .route("route3", r -> r.path("/myroute")
                            .and().header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                            .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> {
                                if (!requestBody.contains("baidu") && !requestBody.contains("so")) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            })
                            .uri("https://www.360.com/"))
                    .build();
        }
    }
```